# Query to find Installed Location of an application with SQL or WQL

Tags: sql, sccm, wql

I'm trying to build a WQL or SQL Query in order to find the Install Location of any application. The goal is not to have False Positives when cleaning old versions, because it was manually installed by a super user without using the SCCM Package, so we need to detect all machines with those properties I mentionned before.

Let's say our application could be installed regularly on (%ProgramFiles% or %ProgramFiles(x86)%) but sometimes you have applications that can be installed also on locations like: (%appdata%, %localappdata% or %programdata%).

I know that many applications will not report the Registry value: InstallLocation from: HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Uninstall\
So, this will leave us few possibilities to find the current location of your application.

WQL:

`select SMS_G_System_ADD_REMOVE_PROGRAMS.Version, SMS_G_System_ADD_REMOVE_PROGRAMS.ProdID, SMS_R_System.Name, SMS_R_System.ResourceType, SMS_R_System.ResourceDomainORWorkgroup, SMS_G_System_COMPUTER_SYSTEM.SystemType, SMS_R_System.Client, SMS_R_System.ResourceId from  SMS_R_System inner join SMS_G_System_COMPUTER_SYSTEM on SMS_G_System_COMPUTER_SYSTEM.ResourceID = SMS_R_System.ResourceId inner join SMS_G_System_ADD_REMOVE_PROGRAMS on SMS_G_System_ADD_REMOVE_PROGRAMS.ResourceID = SMS_R_System.ResourceId where SMS_G_System_ADD_REMOVE_PROGRAMS.DisplayName like "%{ApplicationName}%" order by SMS_G_System_ADD_REMOVE_PROGRAMS.Version DESC`

SQL:

`Select ARPDisplayName0 [Product], ProductVersion0 [Version], UninstallString0 [Uninstall String], count(*) [Installations] from v_GS_INSTALLED_SOFTWARE as swd 
where ARPDisplayName0 like '{ApplicationName}%'
group by ARPDisplayName0, ProductVersion0, UninstallString0
order by [Installations] desc`

I would like to build this WQL/SQL Query, in order to find the following resources: Version, Product ID, Workstation Name, Resource Type, Domain, SystemType, Client, Resource ID, Uninstall String and Installed Location.

Notice that Installed Location results are always empty.
If you may give me some hints on what to add or modify will be very appreciated.

Kind regards.

Comment: Are you sure that this is even possible when you already know that many applications do not properly report installlocation in the registry? I think the tables you are using rely on exactly those registry values. You could try to use software inventory to get the locations for the executables but it would leave you with only file version and location, so you would need to figure the uninstall part out in whatever script you deploy to them (however in my experience you cannot rely on automated uninstall via uninstall property for non msi setups anyway)

Comment: You are correct ! And I was thinking about the ARPINSTALLLOCATION.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/msi/arpinstalllocation

But I'm not sure if its possible.

Comment: I'm not sure either. What I'd propose is using software inventory and only filtering for file location and version number (to filter out backups and odd versions early). Afterwards deploy to all those machines and in the script do the more complicated checks (could even check sccm execution history), and in case the program is detected as sccm installed or does match whatever your criteria is do nothing, in case it is not correct it. That way you can use a complex script and do not have to figure out everything in the query already.

Comment: I see your point Syberdoor, but I think will be a bit complicated that way. I thought that with SQL could be possible to get that info. I'm not trying to get all the machines inventory, but just do a search for an individual application. This query may work for others if needed. I'm just trying to keep things simple.